# Spring Boot - Same repository and same entity for different databases (name difference)

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa

I have almost 5 database that have difference name.
for example -> cat_1 , cat_2 ,...
How to get data from them? (instead to create seperate entity for each them.)

I need code sample
or another way.

Comment: just for clarify, 5 databases or tables ?

Comment: Does this solve your problem?
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases

Comment: @rioswarawan is no different, I prefer 5 databases.

Comment: @dimnnv this is used for 2 different data sources and entity.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use Entity, you can query it by yourself using `EntityManagerFactory`.

```
val result: List<T> = EntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager()
    .createNativeQuery(queryInString)
    .getResultList()
```

Comment: good idea, but I prefer to use entity.